# На ios мобильная версия сайта выходит из краев

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть сайт, который в браузерах открывается нормально, не растягивается. Но на ios через сафари или хром если попытаться сдвинуть его в бок или уменьшить, то он спокойно выходит из своих рамок и сужается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какими способами это можно поправить?

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

попробуйте этот метатег применить